# Tel Href Link Regex

Tags: function, hyperlink

Using this code to return a telephone number:

```
<a href="tel:<?php $stel = get_field('fl_telephone');echo $stel; ?>">
```

However the variable `fl_telephone` is formatted as

```
+44 (0) 1234 567 890
```

and i need to convert it to:

```
+441234567890
```

i.e. without (0) and spaces. In javascript I found this solution but how do i implement the regular expresssion for my functions code in wordpress?

```
$('a[href^="tel:"]').attr('href', function(_,v){
    return v.replace(/\(0\)|\s+/g,'')
});
```

Comment: hmmm, simple php questions should be asked on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it this way:

```
$stel = '+44 (0) 1234 567 890';
$stel = preg_replace( '/\(0\)|\s+/', '', $stel );
```

For more detail take a look at [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.